# Python, statsmodels, adding confidence intervals to binary logistic regression plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels, logistic-regression, confidence-interval

I wonder if there is an easy-to-use-command to add confidence intervals to logistic regression model plots using statsmodels as there is for R. By now... I'm getting stuck with wls_prediction_std which is obviously not suitable for logReg.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which "logistic regression model plots"? What's the command in R to get this?  If you mean confidence intervals for the predicted probabilities, then the current answer is that it is not directly available, but there might be a simple workaround.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for the fast reply. Sorry for "coming back here". So, you are totally righht, I mean confidence intervals for the predicted probabilities. Unfortunately, the R- package I heard about is a homemade workaround as well. If you could help me with that, it would be great. MAny thanks, Veit.

Comment: After I did quite some search, I found a nice and wasy to apply workaround: http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fscikit-learn.org%2F0.8%2F_images%2Fplot_gp_regression_1.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fscikit-learn.org%2F0.8%2Fauto_examples%2Fgaussian_process%2Fplot_gp_regression.html&h=600&w=800&tbnid=WdrpdBwQ7WhA1M%3A&zoom=1&docid=DaT2b6dLYAk9iM&ei=R2cqVJi4OYndaICCgagL&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=2666&page=1&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=0CCIQrQMwAA.